# How to show and hide the background player in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm working on a project where I have two separate UIViewControllers, one to initiate an audio player and one to stream youtube videos. My requirement is to initiate the background player when playing the audios and completely take off the background player when playing videos. For now it works fine for the audio player, but when streaming and goes to back ground it still shows the player. My code as bellow.

Audio Player

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                print("AVAudioSession is Active")
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
 }
```

Video Player

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground()-> Void{
        self.videoPlayer.pauseVideo() 

        //What to do here after pausing the video???    

    }
```

Comment: First off, why are you nesting the do-catch statements?, unless you need specific error handling I think you only need one. Second, we need the part of the code you use to stop/play the audio and stop/play the YouTube video.

Comment: Nesting doesnt cause any issue as of now, its to safe gourd in case i nee to handle things specifically in AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback mode. my issue is to hide when enter the background  in video screen, which im unable after few attempts